# Laravel orderBy on a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am looping over all comments posted by the Author of a particular post.

```
foreach($post->user->comments as $comment)
{
    echo "<li>" . $comment->title . " (" . $comment->post->id . ")</li>";
}
```

This gives me

```
I love this post (3)
This is a comment (5)
This is the second Comment (3)
```

How would I order by the post_id so that the above list is ordered as 3,3,5

Answer (score 378, accepted):

It is possible to extend the relation with query functions:

```
<?php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment')->orderBy('column');
}
```

[edit after comment]

```
<?php
class User
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}

class Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $column = Input::get('orderBy', 'defaultColumn');
        $comments = User::find(1)->comments()->orderBy($column)->get();

        // use $comments in the template
    }
}
```

default User model + simple Controller example; when getting the list of comments, just apply the orderBy() based on Input::get().
(be sure to do some input-checking ;) )

Comment: Thanks Rob, you put me on the right track. The actual answer was $comments = User::find(10)->comments()->orderBy('post_id')->get(); It seemed to need the get() method in order to work. If you can add get() to your answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This works well if you're retrieving a single record, but if you are retrieving multiple records you'll want something more along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/a/26130907/1494454

Comment: If you use mysql strict mode, which is default in Laravel 5.4 ,f.ex you'll receive SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns ...

Answer (score 41):

In cases where you don't want the sort to be part of the relationship definition as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143469), you can also pass an array to the `Eloquent::with()` method. The key indicates the relationship name, and the value is a function that is passed the `Builder` object:

```php
$sortDirection = 'desc';

$user->with([
    'comments' => fn ($query) => $query->orderBy('column', $sortDirection);
]);
```

That allows you to run arbitrary logic on each related comment record. You could have stuff in there like:

```
$query->where('timestamp', '<', $someTime)->orderBy('timestamp', $sortDirection);
```

Comment: Nope. I have tried this, it doesn't work. 
Here's my case : I have two table (`appointments` and `schedules`), the query is simple : get `appointments` order by `schedules`.`datetime` descending.
I have solution by adding new column in table `appointments` to store `datetime` from table `schedules`. And now I only need to order by `appointments`.`datetime`
I know it's not best method, but it solve the problem. XD

Comment: That would only sort the subquery, not the parent query.

Comment: The same applies for `load()` method.

Answer (score 21):

Using `sortBy...` could help.

`$users = User::all()->with('rated')->get()->sortByDesc('rated.rating');`

Comment: Note that this sorts the collection, and not in the query. You achieve the same result, but sorting is done in PHP and not SQL, which may have performance implications.

Comment: Get this error........
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'omsOptionDetails.sort' in 'order clause'

Comment: Who cares about the performance and memory usage, right?

Comment: Well I would cache the results for an hour or more depending on traffic and amount of data retrieved.   Looking at the original question, comments on a post is not critical, otherwise looking into sockets would be a better direction then its time to optimise the query.

Answer (score 14):

Try this solution.

```
$mainModelData = mainModel::where('column', $value)
    ->join('relationModal', 'main_table_name.relation_table_column', '=', 'relation_table.id')
    ->orderBy('relation_table.title', 'ASC')
    ->with(['relationModal' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('column', 'value');
    }])->get();
```

**Example:**

```
$user = User::where('city', 'kullu')
    ->join('salaries', 'users.id', '=', 'salaries.user_id')
    ->orderBy('salaries.amount', 'ASC')
    ->with(['salaries' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('amount', '>', '500000');
    }])->get();
```

You can change the column name in `join()` as per your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

I made a trait to order on a relation field. I had this issues with webshop orders that have a status relation, and the status has a name field.

[Example of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZiY8.png)

Ordering on with "joins" of eloquent models is not possible since they are not joins. They are query's that are running after the first query is completed. So what i did is made a lil hack to read the eloquent relation data (like table, joining keys and additional wheres if included) and joined it on the main query. This only works with one to one relationships.

The first step is to create a trait and use it on a model. In that trait you have 2 functions. The first one:

```
/**
 * @param string $relation - The relation to create the query for
 * @param string|null $overwrite_table - In case if you want to overwrite the table (join as)
 * @return Builder
 */
public static function RelationToJoin(string $relation, $overwrite_table = false) {
    $instance = (new self());
    if(!method_exists($instance, $relation))
        throw new \Error('Method ' . $relation . ' does not exists on class ' . self::class);
    $relationData = $instance->{$relation}();
    if(gettype($relationData) !== 'object')
        throw new \Error('Method ' . $relation . ' is not a relation of class ' . self::class);
    if(!is_subclass_of(get_class($relationData), Relation::class))
        throw new \Error('Method ' . $relation . ' is not a relation of class ' . self::class);
    $related = $relationData->getRelated();
    $me = new self();
    $query = $relationData->getQuery()->getQuery();
    switch(get_class($relationData)) {
        case HasOne::class:
            $keys = [
                'foreign' => $relationData->getForeignKeyName(),
                'local' => $relationData->getLocalKeyName()
            ];
        break;
        case BelongsTo::class:
            $keys = [
                'foreign' => $relationData->getOwnerKeyName(),
                'local' => $relationData->getForeignKeyName()
            ];
        break;
        default:
            throw new \Error('Relation join only works with one to one relationships');
    }
    $checks = [];
    $other_table = ($overwrite_table ? $overwrite_table : $related->getTable());
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        array_push($checks, $key);
        array_push($checks, $related->getTable() . '.' . $key);
    }
    foreach($query->wheres as $key => $where)
        if(in_array($where['type'], ['Null', 'NotNull']) && in_array($where['column'], $checks))
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
    $query = $query->whereRaw('`' . $other_table . '`.`' . $keys['foreign'] . '` = `' . $me->getTable() . '`.`' . $keys['local'] . '`');
    return (object) [
        'query' => $query,
        'table' => $related->getTable(),
        'wheres' => $query->wheres,
        'bindings' => $query->bindings
    ];
}
```

This is the "detection" function that reads the eloquent data.

The second one:

```
/**
 * @param Builder $builder
 * @param string $relation - The relation to join
 */
public function scopeJoinRelation(Builder $query, string $relation) {
    $join_query = self::RelationToJoin($relation, $relation);
    $query->join($join_query->table . ' AS ' . $relation, function(JoinClause $builder) use($join_query) {
        return $builder->mergeWheres($join_query->wheres, $join_query->bindings);
    });
    return $query;
}
```

This is the function that adds a scope to the model to use within query's. Now just use the trait on your model and you can use it like this:

```
Order::joinRelation('status')->select([
    'orders.*',
    'status.name AS status_name'
])->orderBy('status_name')->get();
```