# Ordering Related Models with Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Is it possible to use an `orderBy` for an object's related models?  That is, let's say I have a Blog Post model with a `hasMany("Comments");`  I can fetch a collection with

```
$posts = BlogPost::all();
```

And then run through each post, and display the comment's last edited date for each one

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    {
        echo $comment->edited_date,"\n";
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to set the order the comments are returned in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned object from the relationship is an Eloquent instance that supports the functions of the query builder, so you can call query builder methods on it.

```php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($post->comments()->orderBy('edited_date')->get() as $comment) {
        echo $comment->edited_date,"\n";
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind when you `foreach()` all posts like this, that Laravel has to run a query to select the comments for the posts in each iteration, so [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) the comments like you see in [Jarek Tkaczyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130907/1494454) is recommended.

You can also create an independent function for the ordered comments like you see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship).

```php
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment')->orderBy('comments.edited_date');
}
```

And then you can loop them like you did in your original code.

Comment: Ah, I was missing `get` -- also, shouldn't that be a call to the `comments` method?  If I try it with the magic property I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()`

Answer (score 19):

This is the correct way:

```
BlogPost::with(['comments' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('whatever');
}])->get();
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct way! If you need the flexibility of setting order per-query, this is the only solution that doesn't make new queries for every item. This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a JOIN and select just the column you want to order on:

```
$post = BlogPost::join('comments', function($j) {
        $j->on('posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id');
        $j->select('comment_date_or_other_col');
     })
     ->orderBy('comment_date_or_other_col', 'DESC')->first();
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes:

```
$posts = BlogPost::with('comments')
           ->orderBy('comments_table_name.column_name')
           ->get();
```

And you can also set that in your relation:

```
public comments()
{
    $this->hasMany("Comments")->orderBy('comments.column_name');
}
```

Comment: +1 for `with` -- I hadn't seen that pne yet.  However, the `orderBy` seems to be applying itself to to the first query (select * from blog_posts), and not the second.  Is there a different syntax for applying the order by and/or do you relations need to be setup in a certain way? (referring to the BlogPost::with code here, not directly adding things to the relation)

Comment: This is wrong, you can't reference related table like this, for it's not used in the main query (on which you apply orderBy)