# Get latest message (row) per user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

TL;DR: Need latest message from each sender.

In my Laravel application I have two tables:

Users:

- id
- name

Messages:

- id
- sender_id
- recipient_id
- body
- created_at

And of course models.

User model:

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id');
}
```

Messages model:

```
public function sender() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'sender_id');
}

public function recipient() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient_id');
}
```

When user opens his inbox, he should see list of latest message from any other user.

So if there are messages:

```
id sender_id recipient_id body created_at
1, 2,        1,           hi,  2016-06-20 12:00:00
2, 2,        1,           hi,  2016-06-21 12:00:00
3, 3,        1,           hi,  2016-06-20 12:00:00
4, 3,        1,           hi,  2016-06-21 12:00:00
```

Then user with id 1 (recipient_id) should see only messages with id 2 and 4.

This is current solution in Users model:

```
return Message::whereIn('id', function($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('max(`id`)')
                ->from('messages')
                ->where('recipient_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->groupBy('sender_id');
            })->select('sender_id', 'body', 'created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

This is working, but I was wandering if it is possible to achieve this the Laravel way. Probably with eager loading. My Laravel skills just not enough and after several days of trying I don't have a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this solution is completely fine. What is it about this solution that bothers you exactly?

Comment: Just that I thought there is a more correct and clean way to do it in Laravel.

Comment: I would be more concerned with how many queries your function is taking and how long those queries take.

Comment: You can't group by if you use mysql strict as it violates SQL-92. Laravel 5.4 has strict as default

Comment: Is there any particlar reason for using whereIn ??

Comment: Sory I wasn't attentive enough, you may use group by in conjunction with aggregates, so I find the answer of Trakus Ret the clearest. Just found one post https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/. Wondering if it is possible to do it some how like here

Comment: Simply \Auth::user()->messages()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first() won't work?

Comment: If I may ask, The messages you are trying to fetch is for a particular user. right? i.e not for all users.

Comment: Omisakin, yes it is, for particular user -recepient. He should receive a list of users (senders) with the last message and ordered by created_at/id of the last message

Comment: I updated my answer according to above comment. Please check if it suites you.

Comment: The solution you are considering is not functional, I think that if the user with id 1 replies to id 2 or id 3, the last message that will be displayed will be the one sent from id 2 or id 3, then in the end it will not show the last message of the conversation

Answer (score 9):

Taking inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/7377984), the most efficient way to do this would be like so:

```
DB::table('messages AS m1')
    ->leftjoin('messages AS m2', function($join) {
        $join->on('m1.sender_id', '=', 'm2.sender_id');
        $join->on('m1.id', '<', 'm2.id')
    })->whereNull('m2.id')
    ->select('m1.sender_id', 'm1.body', 'm1.created_at')
    ->orderBy('m1.created_at', 'm1.desc')->get();
```

While it is not the most Laravel friendly, it is the best solution based on performance as highlighted by the post linked in this answer above

Comment: What are the benefits of this solution, comparing with the answer of question author?

Comment: The OP's solution is exactly the same at the post's 1st query is (execution time: 1 min 17.89 secs). Whereas the query I've mentioned (post's 2nd query) is much faster (0.28 secs). This is a performance enhancement of over 275 times!

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply accessing the `messages`, like this -

```
// get the authenticated user
$user = \Auth::user(); 

// find the messages for that user
return User::with('message')->find($user->id)->messages;
```

Comment: Because it will return all messages the user received. But I need only the latest one from each sender.

Comment: Ok, it was not very clear from your question before. Anyway, if u want that, an alternate solution could be to keep a "is_read" flag in your `messages` table with default value as `N`. Later, once the message is read you can update it to `Y`. This way you can only filter `is_read = 'N'` records and avoid the `max()` query

Comment: Actually i do have this flag (question simplified). However, it's still no use. If the user got several new messages from several other users, they all will have this flag (not read). So basically it's the same problem, only with another column in results.

Comment: Your answer still returns all the messages. What you are doing is "getting all the messages for the first user" which is not as same as "getting latest message per user"

Answer (score 1):

this may be a solution (not tested though)

```
User::with([
'messages' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('sender_id', 'body')->groupBy('sender_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
])->find(1);
```

Comment: This IS the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some similar approach and found out you only need to orderBy `created_at` immediately you find all the messages of the `User` then you can use Laravel's `Collection` to group them them by `sender_id`. So to my understanding, the following approach should work, i.e give you the last message receive *by the user* from the *sender**s*** :

So assuming you have an Authenticated `User` as `$user` which in this context is the same as `receiver` with `receiver_id` in `messages` table, then:

```
$messages = $user->messages()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get(['sender_id', 'body', 'created_at'])
    ->groupBy('sender_id'); //this is collections method
```

Then loop round the collection, and fetch the first:

```
$result =  new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection ();
foreach ($messages as $message){
    $result->push($message->first()); //the first model in the collection is the latest message
}
```

You should end up with the result such as:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#875
     all: [
       App\Message {#872
        sender_id: "2",
        body: "hi",
        created_at: "2016-06-21 12:00:00",
      },
      App\Message {#873
        sender_id: "4",
        body: "hi",
        created_at: "2016-06-21 12:00:00",
      },
    ]
```

> PS: A note is that I can't say how efficient this might be but one thing is for sure, is the limited number of query on the db.

Hope it helps :)

**UPDATE**:

I will break it down as I tried it. ~

It fetches all records of `messages` that belongs to user into a collection (already ordered by created_at) then, using [laravel's groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) you have a result like the example given in that doc.

[image: Laravel's groupBy()]

This time I didnt convert to Array. Instead, its a collection Of Collections. like *collection(collection(Messages))*

Then you pick the first Model at each index. The parameters I already passed into the `get()` method ensures only those fields are present (i.e `->get(['sender_id', 'body', 'created_at'])`. This is is totally different from mysql groupBy(), as it does not return one row for each group rather, simply groups all records by the given identifier.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I discovered later that calling `unique()` method on the resulting ordered messages would actually do the job, but in this case the unique identifier would be `sender_id`. (ref: [Laravel's unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique))That is:

```
$messages = $user->messages()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get(['sender_id', 'body', 'created_at'])
    ->unique('sender_id'); //unique replaces `groupBy`
```

The consequence is that we don't need the `foreach` and the `groupBy` we have the result here.

One other way to avoid repeatition (of the above) if this is needed in more than one place is to use [Laravel's query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) i.e in `Message` model we can have something as this:

```
public function scopeLatestSendersMessages($query) 
{
     return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
         ->get(['sender_id', 'body', 'created_at'])
         ->unique('sender_id');
}
```

Then in the controller use:

```
$messages = $user->messages()->latestSendersMessages();
```

PS: Still not sure which one is optimally better than the other.

Comment: How does the laravel's collection method groupBy defines which values to return? I mean which field to return in 'body', 'created_at'? We may also use similar approach with mysql method GROUP BY, but it's not recommended in strict mysql. Are there any issues with laravel's approach?

Comment: I will give an answer to this as update in my answer.

Comment: I understood what you mean. You fetch all the raws from database and filter them on the back-end. I guess, when data grows this approach would be less efective. Thank you for your answer anyway + for clarity.

Comment: @Sabine I have another update answer (you can check). Discovered this when playing around with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I like a simpler approach which is mentioned [here](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/).

In your `User` model additionally to existing `messages()` relationship,  add this relationship

```
public function latestMessage() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class, 'recipient_id')->latest();
}
```

Then when you query simply query like this.

```
$messages = User::with('latestMessage')->get();
```

`$messages` contains latest message per user.

**Edit**

In order to order the result by datetime/id you could do it like this.

```
$messages = User::with(['latestMessage' => function($message) {
    $message->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

`$messages` contains latest message per user ordered by `id`. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130907/3918473)

Comment: AFAIU, that doesn't order users in collection, based on the datatime/id of the last message, am I wrong?

Comment: @Sabine thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer with how to order the result. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution in another forum, I think that is what you were looking for. I post it so it can be useful for other users

```
        DB::select('
            SELECT t1.*
            FROM messages AS t1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id) AS user_id,
                    GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id) AS recipient_id,
                    MAX(id) AS max_id
                FROM messages
                GROUP BY
                    LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id),
                    GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id)
            ) AS t2
                ON LEAST(t1.sender_id, t1.recipient_id) = t2.sender_id AND
                   GREATEST(t1.sender_id, t1.recipient_id) = t2.recipient_id AND
                   t1.id = t2.max_id
                WHERE t1.sender_id = ? OR t1.recipient_id = ?
            ', [auth()->guard('api')->user()->id, auth()->guard('api')->user()->id]);
```

*original post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-the-latest-message-of-chat-model-with-mysql-just-cannot-get-the-idea-how-to-do-this?page=1#reply=392529*

Answer (score 0):

This is the most "Eloquent way" I have found of doing this:

In User model:

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'recipient_id');
}

public function latestMessagePerSender()
{
    return $this->messages()
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->from('messages AS m2')
                ->whereRaw('m2.sender_id = messages.sender_id')
                ->whereRaw('m2.created_at > messages.created_at');
    });
}
```

Then just `$user->latestMessagePerSender`

Comment: This is still a subquery and not a join. Suffers from slow performance like I've highlighted

Comment: @Paras well, that post says "Regarding performance, one solution or the other can be better, depending on the nature of your data. So you should test both queries and use the one that is better at performance given your database." Also, this solution doen't do joins, rather it uses the `EXISTS` operator, which is pretty fast since it doesn't load results, and "returns true" once it finds a match. Having said that, I have to say I didn't do benchmarks, and the OP should do his own tests anyway to find the best method for their case.

Comment: Agreed @Alejandro. However, for most cases the join has better performance due to O(n2) is null comparisons. Your post uses the exists operator but nevertheless is a `subquery`. Check it out by adding `DB::listen` to log the queries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one:

```
        $user = \Auth::user(); 

        // Get the latest date
        $last_date_created = Message::latest()->first()->created_at; // also check for possible null

        // Get the date only - use to specify date range in the where section in the eloquent query
        $target_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $last_date_created ) );

        // Retrieve the messages
        $latest_posts = Message::where('recipient_id', $user->id)
                               ->where('created_at', '>=', $target_date . ' 00:00:00')
                               ->where('created_at', '<=',  $target_date . ' 23:59:59')
                               ->groupBy('sender_id')
                               ->groupBy('created_at')
                               ->get();

        return $latest_posts;
```

This may not be very efficient since it took two queries to do the job but you will gain benefits thru code readability.

I hope it works the way it should be. I haven't tested it though but that's how I usually do this... Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one

```
Messages::where('recipient_id',**{USER_ID}**)
          ->group_by('sender_id')
          ->order_by('id','desc')
          ->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it groups first by sender, giving the message with lowest id for each sender (although I wouldn't trust this behavior is consistent), and then it orders on that result. That's why more complex solutions exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group