# Get thread of conversations including the last message using laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I'm having trouble trying to get the last message for each conversation and the number of unread messages using the model relationship:

```
|id | user_id | recipient_to |    message        | read | created_at | updated_at | 
+---+---------+--------------+-------------------+------+------------+------------+
| 1 |    1    |      2       | Hi                |  1   |            |            |
| 2 |    2    |      1       | How are you?      |  1   |            |            |   
| 3 |    1    |      3       | Hi                |  0   |            |            |
| 4 |    1    |      2       | Could you help me?|  0   |            |            |
```

I have built the query that retrieves the thread of conversations of a specific user including the relation to the recipient:

Model: App\Models\Message.php

```
public function userTo()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'recipient_to', 'id');
}
```

Controller

```
$conversations = Message::where('user_id', 1)
     ->with([
        'userTo' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'last_name', 'avatar');
         }
     ])
     ->distinct()
     ->get(['recipient_to']);
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "recipient_to": 2,
        "user_to": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jessyca",
            "last_name": "Skiles",
            "avatar": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=hayes.rachael@example.org"
        }
    },
    {
        "recipient_to": 3,
        "user_to": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Rocio",
            "last_name": "Rosenbaum",
            "avatar": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?u=yspencer@example.org"
        }
    }
]
```

How could I build the relationship that returns the last message and the number of unread messages?

***I have already read this post, I consider it very interesting, although the purpose is to study the relations of Laravel
[Get latest message (row) per user in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120810/get-latest-message-row-per-user-in-laravel)***

> **21/08/2019 --- Progress**

If I create two relationships in the User model, I get the last message sent from each user in the conversation, is there any way to create an additional relationship and merge to return the most recent?

```
public function latestMessageTo()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Message', 'recipient_to')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->latest();
}

public function latestMessageFrom()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Message', 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->latest();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, don't use eloquent, however it satisfies the need.

Perhaps we could find a solution using eloquent, although I have read that it's more efficient to use a native SQL query instead of eloquent.

```
         DB::select('
            SELECT t1.*
            FROM messages AS t1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    LEAST(user_id, recipient_to) AS user_id,
                    GREATEST(user_id, recipient_to) AS recipient_to,
                    MAX(id) AS max_id
                FROM messages
                GROUP BY
                    LEAST(user_id, recipient_to),
                    GREATEST(user_id, recipient_to)
            ) AS t2
                ON LEAST(t1.user_id, t1.recipient_to) = t2.user_id AND
                   GREATEST(t1.user_id, t1.recipient_to) = t2.recipient_to AND
                   t1.id = t2.max_id
                WHERE t1.user_id = ? OR t1.recipient_to = ?
            ',[auth()->guard('api')->user()->id, auth()->guard('api')->user()->id]);
```

any opinion?

*I want to give credit to the publication where I found the query: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-the-latest-message-of-chat-model-with-mysql-just-cannot-get-the-idea-how-to-do-this?page=1#reply=392529*