# internal orderBy gets overwritten by external orderBy in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a reliationship `User hasOne Position` and I'm fetching the users, but I want to sort them first by `Position->name` and then by `User->name`.  I tried the following

```php
<?php
$sorted = Position::where('groupId', $this->groupId)
    ->whereIn('id', $positions)
    ->with(['user' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('user.name'); // internal sort
    }])
    ->orderBy('position.name') // external sort
    ->get();
```

This way the results are sorted by the external sort only, or, by Position->name. Different users with the same Position->name are listed unsorted. If I remove the external sort, and leave only the sortBy User->name, it works, BUT only for the names, while positions are random.

I have tried different ways

- setting the order in the `Position->user` relationship, does not work
- setting the order in the `User->position` relationship, does not work
- defining only an external `orderBy('position.name, user.name')`, crashes, saying user table is not in the query.

I also tried following similar questions like

- [Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)
- [Ordering Related Models with Laravel/Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130101/ordering-related-models-with-laravel-eloquent/26130907#26130907)

but they don't seem to be trying to sort the results both by the parent and the relationship. It seems my only solution is to walk the result and sort them in PHP instead of from the DB, but this sounds dumb.

Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Not sure but try if there is a function addOrderBy()

Comment: @FrankB `Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::addOrderBy() ` Looks like that's the Doctrine way.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to sort the parent `Position` by the relationship `User`, you need to use a `join()`:

```
$sorted = Position::where(...)
->whereIn(...)
->with('user')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'positions.user_id') // Or whatever the join logic is
->orderBy('users.name')
->orderBy('positions.name')
->get();
```

Note: The `orderBy()` on the `user` relationship within `with()` doesn't seem necessary, as by convention, a singular-named relationship should only return 1 record, and sorting on a single record is pointless.

This will return a `Collection` of `Position` models, with an attached `User` model, sorted by the User's name, then the Position's name. You might need to add a `select('positions.*')` to avoid any ambiguity issues, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: It "works". I had to add the `select('positions.*')` as you said, so data from one table does not overwrite the other one, BUT, I'm redefining the relationship, instead of reusing it, which seems a bit of a workaround instead of the right solution.

It "works". Thank you.

Comment: @StR If you want to sort the main model based on the value of a relationship there's no other way to do it since the model query happens separately from the relationship query otherwise.

Comment: You're not exactly redefining the relationship, you're adding additional logic for a sort. You could define this join/sort as a Scope, like `scopeSortUser()`, then you'd just have to call `Position::sortUser()->get();`. The `with('user')` isn't actually required here, but it does speed up the query if you try to access `$position->user->name` later.