# Laravel: how to sort a collection with hasMany field

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have five tables:

`details` having fields `id`, `name` and has hasMany relation with contributions.

`purpose` having fields `id`, `name` and has hasMany relation with contributions.

`period` having fields `id`, `name` and has hasMany relation with contributions.

`user` having fields `id`, `name` and has hasMany relation with contributions.

and

contributions having `id`, `amount` and "belongsTo" relation with `user_id, detail_id, purpose_id, period_id`

Now, I want to get all `contributions` of a specific `user` (filtered by `user_id`) and then sort the result by `period.name`, `detail.name` and `purpose.name`.

Any suggestions?

The question has been identified as possible duplicate of [Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship) . However there is a basic difference.

there, there is relation between user and comment & user and post. however in my case, there isn't any relation between user and details/purposes/periods tables.

```
<?php
class User
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

is possible in that case, but by same analogy, in my case, class User doesn't have any details() function to get hasMany relations. My user has relation with only contributions table and contributions table has relations with details purpose etc tables.

hope I am able to clarify the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)

Comment: have you tried the most voted answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130101/ordering-related-models-with-laravel-eloquent/26130907#26130907](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130101/ordering-related-models-with-laravel-eloquent/26130907#26130907) ?  of course you would have to add each relation in the method `Contributions::with(['details' => (), 'purpose ' => (), 'period ' => (), 'user ' ])`