# Select newest prices for each shop

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to get the newest prices of all products for each shop. My table setup is like this:

## Table: products

<kbd>**Name**</kbd>       <kbd>**Type**</kbd>             <kbd>**Collation**</kbd>        <kbd>**Attributes**</kbd>   <kbd>**Null**</kbd><kbd>**Default**</kbd><kbd>**Extra**</kbd>                        
<kbd>id</kbd>              <kbd>int(10)</kbd>                                   <kbd>UNSIGNED</kbd><kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>   <kbd>AUTO_INCREMENT</kbd>
<kbd>name</kbd>        <kbd>varchar(255)</kbd><kbd>utf8_unicode_ci</kbd>                  <kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>                                     
<kbd>description</kbd><kbd>text</kbd>              <kbd>utf8_unicode_ci</kbd>                  <kbd>Yes</kbd>  <kbd>Null</kbd>

## Table: products_prices

<kbd>**Name**</kbd>        <kbd>**Type**</kbd>              <kbd>**Collation**</kbd>        <kbd>**Attributes**</kbd>   <kbd>**Null**</kbd><kbd>**Default**</kbd>                      <kbd>**Extra**</kbd>                        
<kbd>id</kbd>               <kbd>int(10)</kbd>                                    <kbd>UNSIGNED</kbd><kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>                         <kbd>AUTO_INCREMENT</kbd>
<kbd>shop_id</kbd>     <kbd>int(10)</kbd>                                    <kbd>UNSIGNED</kbd><kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>                                                           
<kbd>product_id</kbd> <kbd>int(10)</kbd>                                    <kbd>UNSIGNED</kbd><kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>                                                           
<kbd>price</kbd>          <kbd>decimal(10,2)</kbd>                                            <kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>None</kbd>                                                           
<kbd>created_at</kbd> <kbd>timestamp</kbd>                                                 <kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>0000-00-00 00:00:00</kbd>                                    
<kbd>updated_at</kbd><kbd>timestamp</kbd>                                                 <kbd>No</kbd>   <kbd>0000-00-00 00:00:00</kbd>

## Migration: products

```php
Schema::create('products', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
});
```

## Migration: products_prices

```php
Schema::create('products_prices', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->decimal('price', 10, 2);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

## Model: Product

```php
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products';


    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductPrice');
    }

}
```

## Model: ProductPrice

```php
<?php

class ProductPrice extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products_prices';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }

}
```

## Controller

```php
<?php

class ProductController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::with(array('prices'))->get();

        return View::make('products', array('products' => $products));
    }
}
```

So now in my view I have all products with all prices. But I only want to return the newest prices for all shop_ids. For example if I have shop_ids 1, 2, 3 and 4. I would like to return 4 rows per product with the newest price of these shops.

**EDIT:**

When I execute following query directly on mySQL it gives me the correct result, but how do I do this in Eloquent way?

```sql
SELECT * FROM products_prices p JOIN
(SELECT shop_id, product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
FROM products_prices GROUP BY product_id, shop_id) lastEntry
ON p.product_id = lastEntry.product_id AND p.shop_id = lastEntry.shop_id AND p.created_at = lastEntry.created_at;
```

I have succeeded making an Eloquent solution, but I need `DB::raw` in it, could I do it without raw?

```php
$products = Product::with(array(
    'prices' => function($q) {
        $q->join(DB::raw('(SELECT shop_id, product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM products_prices GROUP BY product_id, shop_id) lastEntry'), function($join)
        {
            $join->on('products_prices.product_id', '=', 'lastEntry.product_id');
            $join->on('products_prices.shop_id', '=', 'lastEntry.shop_id');
            $join->on('products_prices.created_at', '=', 'lastEntry.created_at');
        })->orderBy('price', 'asc');
    }
))->get();
```

Comment: you formatted this question like a sir :)

Comment: how did you formatted tables descriptions? is there any tool for this or you did that manually?

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship

Comment: @limonte I did it manually using the `kbd` tag and a lot of spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using some raw querying, like:

```php
  $products = Product::with(array(
    'prices' => function($q) {
      $q->join(DB::raw('(SELECT shop_id, product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM products_prices GROUP BY product_id, shop_id) lastEntry'), function($join)
      {
        $join->on('products_prices.product_id', '=', 'lastEntry.product_id');
        $join->on('products_prices.shop_id', '=', 'lastEntry.shop_id');
        $join->on('products_prices.created_at', '=', 'lastEntry.created_at');
      })->orderBy('price', 'asc');
    }
  ))->get();
```