# How to use orderBy in relationship laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function totalArticles(){
    return $this->updates()->count() + $this->events()->count();
}}
```

here is my model and i wanna use orderBy for this to order form min to max.

Comment: $result = Model_Name::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

Comment: public function totalArticles() {
    return $this->hasMany('.....')->orderBy('tablename.columnname');
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want get records order by created_date

**Ascending:**

```
$result = ModelName::latest();
```

**Descending:**

```
$result = ModelName::oldest();
```

> Other than date

```
$result = ModelName::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();  // ascending
$result = ModelName::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get(); // descending
```