# return related data as an array from sql (left outer) LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have query this query that returns the related images to the comment

```
  return    $comments = \DB::table('comments')->select('comments.comment','comments.user_name','comments.shop_name',
            'comments.rating','comments.created_at','comments_images.images')->
        join('comments_images','comments.id','=','comments_images.comment_id','left outer')
        ->where('comments.product_id', '=', "11644254552")->
orderBy(\DB::raw('-`images`'), 'desc')->get();
```

it returns results like this

```
{

comment: "fdsfdsfsdffddsffds",
user_name: "ahmaf",
shop_name: "example.com",
rating: "4",
created_at: "2017-09-19 02:14:41",
images: https://example.com/kf/UT8.1.cX3XaXXagOFbX5.jpg
},
-{
comment: "fdsfdsfsdffddsffds",
user_name: "ahmaf",
shop_name: "example.com",
rating: "4",
created_at: "2017-09-19 02:14:41",
images: https://example.com/kf/UT81WzoX3BXXXagOFbXs.jpg
},
-{
comment: "sdfdsfdssfd",
user_name: "fdsfds",
shop_name: "example2.myshopify.com",
rating: "5",
created_at: "2017-09-19 02:12:25",
images: null
}
```

as you see the first two rows are duplicated and I want them to be returned like this

```
comment: "fdsfdsfsdffddsffds",
user_name: "ahmaf",
shop_name: "example.com",
rating: "4",
created_at: "2017-09-19 02:14:41",
images:{
 0: https://example.com/kf/UT8.1.cX3XaXXagOFbX5.jpg
 1: https://example.com/kf/UT81WzoX3BXXXagOFbXs.jpg
}
},

-{
comment: "sdfdsfdssfd",
user_name: "fdsfds",
shop_name: "example2.myshopify.com",
rating: "5",
created_at: "2017-09-19 02:12:25",
images: null
}
```

is that possible ?  to return them to gather instead of make new row for each related data.

---

I tried  with it worked, but I couldn't use orderBy images from comments_images table, it only works with columns from comments

```
$comments = Comment::where('product_id', '=', "11644215052")->with([
        'images' => function ($query)
        {
            $query->orderBy('images', 'desc');
        },
    ])->paginate(30);
```

Comment: Try to add `->groupBy('comments.id')->get();` !!

Comment: groupBy won't work, if I do I will have to add all the columns inside it or it will return an error, so it won't  return all the records.  I just want to group the duplicated row together

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a parent/child relationship result.  You won't get that with a flat row result set.  Look at using the laravel model with child relations.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: I know  all of it and I can do it using with (eager load) to return the data together ,but then I won't be able to use orderBy  so I have to use joins, but I couldn't find a solution for this one without eager load

Comment: I don't use Laravel 5, but I know you can set the relationship with ordering.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship

Comment: you can, but not with (eager load) You can't order based on column from anther table. In my case I can't order them using  column from comments_images table.

Comment: With Laravel 4, I'm doing it.  I haven't worked with 5 though.

Comment: Nice, I don't believe there's a big difference between two of them, so can you check this code for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong.  I edited the question.