# Laravel order collection based on property of a one to many related relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a model called Business(having columns description, name, view etc), it has a one to many relationship with the model "Rating". I want to query my Business model such that it returns a result that check if a search string is present in name or description and also sorts by the business having highest rating first then views the business has.

I have written a code for the search query. find below:

```
$business = Business::with('images')
    ->where('isActive', true)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })->get();
```

I know that I can fetch the average ratings of the business like this:

```
$averageRating = Rating::where('business_id', $id)->avg('rating');
$business = Business::with(['images'])->get();

foreach ($business as $item) {
    $item["rating"] = floor($averageRating);
}
```

So, how do I order based on highest ratings first, then highest views

Comment: Possible duplicate question - This should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel orderBy on a relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)

Comment: Why comment 2 times an answer which doesn't fit the question ?

Answer (score 1):

you can  use Subquery Selects:

```
business = Business::with('images')
        ->where('isActive', true)
                    ->where(function ($q) use ($query){
                        $q->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
                    })
->orderByDesc(['topRating' => Rating::select('rating')
    ->whereColumn('business_id', 'businesses.id')
    ->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
    ->limit(1)])
->get();
```

please make sure that to set the business table name instead of  'businesses'

more details about Subquery Selects in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries

Comment: There is a syntax error, the orderByDesc([   is not closed. Besides, is there a reason for the limit please?

Comment: i corrected the syntax error.
for the limit(1) sure it 's necessary .. because you don't want all the rating to be part of ordering ... just only the   highest rating

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to join manualy the table :

```
$business = Business::with('images')
    ->join('rating_table', 'rating_table.business_id', '=', 'business_table.id')
    ->where('isActive', true)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($query){
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('rating_table.value', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

After many tries, it's not possible to order the "parent" by their relationship using Eloquent, you can order inside the relationship, but that's it.

Comment: this get the result ordered by rating_table.value ... not by highest rating like answer wanted

Comment: It returns empty result even no matter the query string

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a join I believe like so:

```php
$business = Business::select([
    'businesses.*', \DB::raw('AVG(ratings.rating) as avg_rating')
  ])
  ->join('ratings', 'businesses.id', '=', 'ratings.business_id')
  ->orderBy('ratings.avg_rating', 'DESC')
  ->get();
```

*Not tested*

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ratings.avg_rating' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `businesses`.*, AVG(ratings.rating) as avg_rating from `businesses` inner join `ratings` on `businesses`.`id` = `ratings`.`business_id` order by `ratings`.`avg_rating` desc) when i tried it