# Sorting in the parent model

Tags: laravel

I have a model in which I am sorting items

```
public static function getArticleBlocks() {
        return ArticleBlock::orderBy('order', 'ASC')->get();
    }
```

This model has a parent `Article` where I output the data with the `ArticleBlock` data

```
public static function getArticle($id) {
        return Article::where('id', $id)->with(['blog_categories', 'article_recommendations', 'article_blocks', 'article_comments'])->first();
    }
```

How can I make the same sorting of `article_blocks` when get `Article`?

Comment: Do you want to sort article based on ```article_blocks``` count ?

Comment: And post the code whatever tried you so far

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I need to sort all `article_blocks` elements correctly so that they go in order, such as order 1, order 2, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143469/8607640 see this answer, set the orderBy in the article_blocks relation like the above answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the hasmany Relation records. You can pass the callback as array value inside with method.

**Rename `sort_column` to your requirement**

```
public static function getArticle($id) 
    {
        return Article::query()
        ->where('id', $id)
                ->with([
                    'blog_categories', 
                    'article_recommendations', 
                    'article_blocks' => function($query){
                    return $query->orderBy('sort_column','ASC');
                    }, 
                    'article_comments'
                ])
                ->first();
    }
```