# Sorting with Laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables `tasks` and `task_hours`, And I'm using one to many relationship in task model.(task can have many hours logs). And displaying task data at frontend in table (datatable) using `with` relationships to `task_hours` (as per query below). I need to sort by `tasks` table's columns (`task_name`, `created_at`) also I need to sort by `total_hours` which is in `task_hours` table, I'm using jQuery DataTable in front-end and getting column name and direction in request at my controller function.

This is my query that is only sorts for tasks table for now but, how can I tell if it is main table's column to sort or relationship table's column to sort ?

```
 $obj1 = Task::with("task_hours");
 $data = $obj1->orderBy($sort_col, $dir)->get()->toArray();
```

Let me know what is the best possible way to sort with laravel relationships? I want to do this while using relationships only and not with join query.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you use laravel yajra-datatables package?

Comment: @Sumitkumar wish I could but, I've to manage in existing flow.

Comment: This [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship)?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem:
As you are using `with` the Task as Task instance with relation object task_hours.
So, to deal with this situation instead of using `with` use join and addSelect:

```
$obj = Task::leftJoin('task_hours', 'task_hours.task_id', 'tasks.id')
             ->select('tasks.*')
             ->addSelect('task_hours.total_hours as total_hours');
$data = $obj->orderBy($sort_col, $dir);
```

This shall fix your issue.
Since we cannot sort through `with` columns we are using normal sql joins and sorting it from sql queries.

### Full Solution

Not optimized but it will get you going since you're using serverside true in datatables:

```
if($request->ajax()){
        $obj = Task::leftJoin('task_hours', 'task_hours.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
                        ->select('tasks.*')
                        ->addSelect('task_hours.total_hours as total_hours');
        //Initialize to data from request
        $order_col = $request->order[0]['column'];
        $order_col_name = $request->columns[$order_col]['data'] ?? $request->columns[$order_col]['name'];
        $order_dir = $request->order[0]['dir'];

        $take = $request->length ?? 10;
        $skip = $request->start ?? 0;

        $totalRecords = $obj->count();

        $data = $obj
                    ->orderBy($order_col_name, strtoupper($order_dir))
                    ->skip($skip)->take($take)
                    ->get();
        return [
            "draw" => $request->draw,
            "recordsTotal" => $totalRecords,
            "recordsFiltered" => $totalRecords,
            "data" => $data
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting all the data anyway you can sort in PHP rather than the database:

```php
$obj1 = Task::with("task_hours");
$data = $obj1->get()->sortBy(function ($val) use ($sort_col) {
   if (array_key_exists($sort_col, $val->getAttributes())) {
      return $val->getAttribute($sort_col);
   }
   if (array_key_exists($sort_col, $val->task_hours->getAttributes())) {
      return $val->task_hours->getAttribute($sort_col);
   }
   return null; 
})->toArray();
```

This avoids the join that would will need to do if you want to order within the SQL query.