# Laravel Sort Posts by the date of the newest comment

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `Posts` table and **polymorphic** relation of `Comments` table.

What I tried (not sure if it is the right way to go) but I get a message that column last_activity does not exist

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

...    

$appends = ['last_activity'];

public function getLastActivityAttribute()
        {
            if($this->has('comments', '>', 0))
            {
                $comment = $this->comments()->getQuery()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
                return $comment->created_at;
            }
            else
            {
                return '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
            }
        }

...

}
```

So basically:

**I want posts ordered by the created_at field of the comment**

with Eloquent. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284911/385402), but it looks like he sorts the comments instead of the posts.

Help?

Comment: Post your attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making this type of calculation has proved to be very resource-inefficient and performed poorly.

Therefore I ended up adding a new database field called `last_activity` and then, with the help of Laravel Events, I attached listeners to update the `last_activity` field.

By doing this I avoided the need to perform a complex query against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ret changing your line to

$this->attributes['last_activity'];

This should retrieve the current last activity when your are calling your model

Comment: This would represent only a performance improvement to store the computed value in a field.